# Place where metamorphosis happens?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, nouns

Is there a name for a place where total character change occurs? A place specifically meant for human inner metamorph?

Metaphorically speaking, it is meant to refer to the place where change occurs as when diamond is created from carbon under immense pressure or how an egg changes when boiled. A place meant to incite inner change.

Comment: I would say a *cocoon*.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Metaphorically speaking, *cocoons* are pretty solidly linked to *protection from external influence/danger*. Perhaps on semantic grounds *chrysalis* comes closer to OP's intended sense, but I can't say I'm familiar with that as a metaphoric usage.

Comment: Some colloquial suggestions -- 'the dark night of the soul', 'the hero's journey' -- come to mind. I don't know if there's an actual place in a person's body for such a metamorphosis as you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metaphorically, an environment where someone is transformed by pressure is a ***[crucible](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/crucible?)***, defined by OALD as

> 2. *(formal or literary)* a place or situation in which people or ideas are tested severely, often creating something new or exciting in the process

In the literal sense, a crucible is a vessel in which a substance is subjected to intense heat, as for liquefying metal to extract it from ore, or for combining them to produce alloys, from which the sense of a severe test, especially a transformative one, naturally follows. Early OED examples include

> 1647 · J. Howell *New Vol. of Lett.* 106   In the limbeck and **crusible** of affliction.
>   1796 · H. Hunter tr. J. H. B. de Saint-Pierre *Stud. Nature* (1799) III. 332   A ship is the **crucible** in which morals are put to the test.

Arthur Miller's 1953 play *[The Crucible](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1996/10/21/why-i-wrote-the-crucible)* refers to the figurative crucible of Puritan Salem, Massachusetts, not to any physical object.